# SELECT all the newest records distinct

Tags: mysql, group-by

i have table structure like this

```
  sn  |  person_id  |   image_name |

   1  |   1         |      abc1.jpb 
   2  |   1         |      aa11.jpg  
   3  |   11        |      dsv.jpg
   4  |   11        |      dssd.jpg
   5  |   11        |      sdf.jpg
```

I need distinct person_id newest row  as following

```
  2   |  1          |  aa11.jjpb
  5   |  11         |  sdf.jpg
```

IT is possible ?

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable GROUP BY person_id ORDER BY sn DESC
```

Essentially you want to select all records from your table.  Then it is grouped by the person_id (limiting the result to 1 per person id)...  Ordering by SN decending means that it will return the most recent (highest) sn

Update:  (and verified)

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM stackoverflow ORDER BY sn DESC) a GROUP BY person_id ORDER BY sn
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM yourtable GROUP BY person_id ORDER BY sn DESC

This Statement is listing descending value of Result .so still not getting what i want

Comment: SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM stackoverflow ORDER BY sn DESC) a GROUP BY person_id

Thank you CarpeNoctumDC This working working fine now

Comment: This works nicely as does Shakti Singh's answer.  For me this one is more readable, especially if your table is an already complicated query.  Does anyone know if there is a performance difference?

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY person_id HAVING MAX(sn)
```

**EDIT**

```
SELECT f.*
FROM (
      SELECT person_id, MAX(sn) as maxval
      FROM  table GROUP BY person_id
     ) AS x INNER JOIN table AS f
ON f.person_id = x.person_id AND f.sn = x.maxval;
```

where table is your table name.

Comment: Upvoted for the MAX...  LOL its too early in the morning to think straight

Comment: SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY person_id HAVING MAX(sn)
 1  |   1         |      abc1.jpb 
 4  |   11        |      dssd.jpg 

Not working Still showing old row

Comment: @G-Rajendra: Sorry. I can not reach here. Check updated answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table a WHERE a.`id` = ( SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM table b WHERE b.`person_id` = a.`person_id` );
```

What you are doing inside the parenthesis is selecting the max `id` for the rows that have that distinct `person_id`. So for each unique `person_id` you are getting the most recent entry.